# Validation error: EntityType has no key defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework

when i  try to create controller i get error call " EntityType has no key defined" . why is that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HotelManagementSystem.Models
{
    public class Room
    {
        public int RoomNo { get; set; }
        public string PackageiD { get; set; }
        public string ResiD { get; set; }
        public bool Tv { get; set; }
        public bool Wifi { get; set; }
        public bool Internet { get; set; }
        public bool Telephone { get; set; }
        public bool Ac { get; set; }
        public bool Bathroom { get; set; }
        public bool Fridge { get; set; }
        public bool Homethearter { get; set; }
    }
    public class RoomContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Room/*table name*/> HotelManagementSystem /*Data Base name */ { get; set; }
}
}
```

erroe message is :[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a property of Id which will be primary key like this:

```
[Key]
public int Id  {get;set;}
```

actually you have not defined primary key in the model.

If **RoomNo** will always be unique in each row, then you can make it primary key.

Comment: I did but give same Error